# Module: S3 bucket for_each with different policy on each

Tags: foreach, module, terraform

I am trying to see if this is possible
Terraform 0.12.28

```
    bucket_names = {
        "bucket1" = "test_temp"
        "bucket2" = "test_jump"
        "bucket3" = "test_run"
    }
    
    module "s3" {
        source = "./modules/s3"
        name = var.bucket_names
        region = var.region
        tags = var.tags
    }
    
    
    module
    resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3" {
        for_each = var.name
        
        bucket                      = "${each.value}"
        region                      = var.region
        request_payer               = "BucketOwner"
        tags                        = var.tags
    
        versioning {
            enabled    = false
            mfa_delete = false
        }
    }
```

Works JUST fine, each bucket is created. BUT now my question is how can i keep a clean way of applying specific policies to each bucket in the list?

```
policy 1 => test1_temp
policy 2 => test2_jump
policy 3 => test2_run
```

Each policy will be slightly different
My thoughts, regex to find _temp and apply policy1 etc

Comment: What value is there here in having this as a module that takes multiple buckets? This seems more complex than using the resources directly or, if your module contains more than just the S3 bucket, then just creating a single S3 bucket and supporting resources for each module call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm with @ydaetkocR on this. It's complexity for no gain in a real system, but it could be interesting for learning.

terraform.tfvars

```
bucket_names = {
    "bucket1" = "test_temp"
    "bucket2" = "test_jump"
    "bucket3" = "test_run"
}

bucket_policy = {
    "bucket1" = <<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "MYBUCKETPOLICY",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "IPAllow",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test_temp/*",
      "Condition": {
         "IpAddress": {"aws:SourceIp": "8.8.8.8/32"}
      }
    }
  ]
}
POLICY
    "bucket2" = "..."
    "bucket3" = "..."
}
```

root module

```
module "s3" {
    source = "./modules/s3"
    name = var.bucket_names
    policy = var.bucket_policies
    region = var.region
    tags = var.tags
}
```

modules/s3

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3" {
    for_each = var.name
    
    bucket                      = each.value
    region                      = var.region
    request_payer               = "BucketOwner"
    tags                        = var.tags

    versioning {
        enabled    = false
        mfa_delete = false
    }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "s3" {
  for_each = var.policy
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3[each.key].id
  policy = each.value
}
```

The trick here is having the same keys for names, policies, and resource instances. You don't have to use two maps, but it's likely the simplest example.

As you can see above it would be a nuisance doing this because you'd have to manually synch the bucket names in the policies or write some *very* elaborate code to substitute the values in your module.

Comment: Thank you, that is so much cleaner

Comment: My pleasure, @Luis :)